# how to commit a transaction in around aspect? creating a db log using around aspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-transactions

I have a method that should be transactional, I am trying to apply DB logging using an Aspect here's what I am trying to do :

- The method I am catching with the aspect should rollback when it throws an exception.
- The `@Around` Aspect should log the request before proceeding the selected method and then log the response.
- In case of an exception in the selected method, the aspect catches that exception and log the exception as well.
- The response / exception log is a table that holds the request log id and the message in case of success or the exception message.
- The aspect will re-throw the exception for the Exception advice to handle it.

Here's the Aspect code

```java
@Transactional
@Around(value = "execution(* com.service.RegistrationService.register(..)) && args(registerRequest)")
public Object afterThrowingAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, RegisterRequest registerRequest) throws Throwable {
    RegistrationRequestLog registrationRequestLog = null;
    try {
       registrationRequestLog = registrationRequestLogService.logRegistrationRequest(registerRequest);

       String result = (String) proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();     
       registrationResponseLogService.logRegistrationResponse(registrationRequestLog, result);
       return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if (registrationRequestLog != null) registrationResponseLogService.logRegistrationResponse(registrationRequestLog, e.getMessage());
       throw e;
    }
}
```

I tried

- Adding `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the register method.
- Adding `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)` on the register method.
  but I got the same result, that in case of exception and when re-throwing the exception the logs do not commit.

*I am using oracle DB - ojdbc8*

Comment: Manually manage the transaction in your aspect for this writing. If you are using annotation the exception will trigger a rollback here.

Comment: shall I manage the transaction using `TransactionTemplate` ?

Comment: That is the easiest way indeed.